# Stop build from gulp in Visual Studio cordova projects

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, gulp, visual-studio-cordova

I need to check some conditions under which a project should not build. Any one know if its possible to stop a build process from a bound gulp task in Visual Studio 2015 Cordova projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some suggestions in the following post:

[Stop Gulp Task if Conditions are met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485162/stop-gulp-task-if-conditions-are-met)

The easiest solution here would be to throw an error from within the task when your "do not build" condition is met. That error will stop the process from continuing.

Comment: Exceptions do stop the task but not the build process.